# Https not working JBoss AS 7.0.2

Tags: ssl, unix, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-12.04, jboss

I am trying to load SSL certificate to one of our site. We are using JBoss AS 7.0.2 for our application on Ubuntu Server 12.04, it's running successfully on http while on https it's not responding. Server is starting successfully without any exception. Kindly suggest the steps to debug this problem.

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host">
            <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http" redirect-port="443"/>
            <connector name="https" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" socket-binding="https" enable-lookups="true" secure="true">
                <ssl password="******" certificate-key-file="/mnt/jboss/******" verify-client="false" certificate-file="/mnt/jboss/********.key"/>
            </connector>
            <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
                <alias name="localhost"/>
                <alias name="example.com"/>
            </virtual-server>
        </subsystem>
```

Comment: Firewall? iptables?

Comment: sudo ufw status
Status: inactive

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer to my question. My port 8443 was closed externally. My bad!